# En Webview como se centra al ancho de la pantalla

Tags: html5, android-studio

estoy ajustando una página web local, al ancho de la pantalla.

Estoy utilizando este código para ajustarlo al ancho de la pantalla

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls( false );
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom( WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR );
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( true );
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);

mWebView.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/pagina.htm" );
```

Como podéis ver en la siguiente imagen, no sale centrado, la línea de números que se tenía que quedar pegada, o con la misma separación en los dos lados, se encuentra pegada al lado derecho.

En cambio, el texto de arriba se muestra mas cerca del lado izquierdo, y la página web tengo puesto que se muestre centrado `<center>`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**menu_2.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.Menu_2">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

¿Hay alguna forma de poder corregirlo?

*Editado*
Como se ha quedado el problema bloqueado y parece que sin solucion, elimino el codigo que nadie tengo problemas con el, ya que no trabaja como tiene que ser.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cual es la imagen de la que hablas?, yo tenía el mismo problema y con  <center> aún no funcionaba , te sugiero agregues tu layout.

Comment: Lo siento, ya he puesto la imagen, y el layout, no solo me pasa con éste `Fragment`, con los demás también pasa, tambien he probado a poner y quitar el `<center>`y se ve igual, da igual que este puesto como si no.

Comment: Gracias @socu el html que cargas tiene <center> ???

Comment: Si, también lo tiene puesto, esa captura es con el puesto, el otro comentairo no se si se puede borrar por completo, estaba escribiendo con el movil, y pulse mal.

Comment: podrías agregar el html, ahí esta la clave en pagina.htm

Comment: @Jorgesys, dejalo aparcado, porque mira como sale esta captura, parece que sale bien http://funkyimg.com/i/2D6sA.png, mañana seguire revisando el codigo que tengo puesto porque me sale en todas las paginas igual, si no encuentro la solucion, ya lo comunico, he craedo una pagina nueva sin codigo, ni nada, vamos solo el texto, y sale bien.

Comment: @Jorgesys he puesto el codigo de la pagina, no es la de la captura, pero pasa lo mismo con esa.